# WPF User Control

Tags: wpf-controls

how to add image in radio button. Image can be change melodramatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Image control to the Content property of the button. Bind the `Source` of the Image to whatever property you wish.

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image Source="{Binding somePropertyThatReturnsAnImage}" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```